# Framelayout Progressbar problems

Tags: android, android-framelayout, layoutparams

Hi I want to make a Progressbar with Framelayouts(one red the other green).
My problem is when I make one bigger, the other Framelayout wont move along. They overlaps.

I have tried to with LayoutParams but it does not work.

```
green.setScaleX(greenscale);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50,50);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, green.getId());
red.setLayoutParams(params);        
greenscale=greenscale+5;
```

xml-File

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/progresswhite"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#CFCFCF" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressgreen"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="#33CC33" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressred"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressgreen"
        android:background="#C12E2E" >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I want it to look like this below:

greeen=#

red=-

```
##------- 
(green.setscale(greenscale)) (greenframe is now bigger)
######------
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LinearLayouts`. `FrameLayout` draws its children one on top of another

Comment: no i did not mean 2 framelayouts below each other
(i did edit my post)

Comment: Actually, you're doing it wrong. This is not how ProgressBar is done. Please check http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-customize-android-progress-bars/ it may help you

Comment: My point is,i want 2 colors if the user pushes the wrong button the red framelayout gets bigger and if the user pushes the right button the greenframelayout gets bigger.
i havent seen this for the progressbar before